# Unable to connect to localhost:5555 from webMethods designer

Tags: localhost, designer, webmethods

Can connect to localhost:5555 Integration server administrator page but not from webMethods Designer 9.10.

Throwing 503 service unavailable error.[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGQJ2.png)

Comment: Can you open localhost:5555 in browser?

Comment: Check your firewall/Internet security software, some inbound ports may be blocked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Could be a proxy issue? Check in Designer your network settings, the "Proxy bypass" settings and the "Active provider" settings.

Comment: Unlikely, when it is a localhost, but may be ;-)

Comment: Uhh, wouldnt be the first time that a request to localhost is routed unintentionally through a proxy... Just give it a try... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Preferences->General->Network Connections Active Provider from HTTP to Direct.

[image: Network Connection Direct]

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you've been waiting long enough? It takes a bit of time, before IS opens up port 5555. Search for the following message in server.log "Enabling HTTP Listener on port 5555" IS is basically unavailable, before that message appears.

Answer (score 0):

You should add localhost to proxy bypass in windows setting